# How to always run an application as different user

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Automatically run an application as another user](https://superuser.com/questions/145575/automatically-run-an-application-as-another-user)
>   ["Run as" for a .bat file](https://superuser.com/questions/105913/run-as-for-a-bat-file)

I have an application which uses floating license concept. We have configured a NT user for acquiring the license.

Now that I have installed this application on our sever which is Windows 2008 R2.

This application is being called by a batch file, which is scheudled.

How can I always make this application run as the specific NT user who has access to the license server?

Comment: this might not work as i call the exe from a batch file. thx for the link

Comment: Then perhaps also check out: [“Run as” for a .bat file](http://superuser.com/questions/105913/run-as-for-a-bat-file) :)

Comment: Also, if you are having trouble running the batch with RunAs, try using RunAs with CMD, and have CMD launch the batch. Something like `runas /u:domain\user "cmd /c batch.bat"`

Comment: actually it was a mistake from my side. I call the batch file from ANT which is called by the build engine.